# DTLS - select always returns there is something to read after socket is closed

Tags: c++, sockets, openssl, dtls

I created a non blocking client/server based on the examples from FH Muenster. Unfortunately, after I close my socket, it doesn't allow me to connect another client to the server.

- I checked on Wireshark and the messages to close the connection are sent correctly.
- Result of Select() (call on server side) function is 0 (time limit expired), however my read fd is not returned empty.
- First client connects successfully, when I try to connect a second client during the handshake, it throws the error "connection refused"

I know that the behavior of select is different with datagrams. My questions are:
- In DTLS is it completely necessary to call listen()?.
- Is it normal that when the timeout expires (select returns 0), the fdSetRead is not empty?

Comment: DTLS is UDP-based, there is no "connection". In any case, "*Is it normal that when the timeout expires (select returns 0), the fdSetRead is not empty?*" - no, it should be empty. The return value is the number of sockets in the returned sets, so a non-empty set with a 0 return value makes no sense. On the other hand, you should not be looking at the returned set unless select() returns > 0 anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I debugged again and noticed that select returns 1, not 0; and it indicates there is something to read. The weird thing is that the socket is already closed, so it shouldn't find anything to read. On both my server and client side I first call SSL_shutdown() and after that I call shutdown(fd, SHUT_RDWR).

Comment: `SSL_shutdown()` sends an SSL close alert message to the peer so it knows to close its side of the session. That could be the data that is triggering a read state in the socket. You should read the message and let OpenSSL handle it. `shutdown()` does not make sense in UDP, only in TCP.  Just close the socket.

Comment: This was not the problem that I was having, but it helped me a lot. Thank you so much! One problem that I was having, was that I didn't create a 2nd socket to connect and keep the first one reading for incoming request. The 2nd problem (which is the same about the read after the connection is closed), is pretty much because my client sends 2 hello client with different sequence numbers in a row, before the verify, but I will open a new question for that

Comment: You don't need 2 sockets, 1 is enough.